# Can't update meteor, because it can't download manifest

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, node.js, software-update, meteor

I've `meteor` installed via `npm` and I'd like to update it, but I can't. I've tried:

```
$ meteor update
Failed to download manifest.
```

but it fails with:

> Failed to download manifest.

So then I've followed the suggestion from [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/689), but it didn't work either:

```
$ curl -vs https://install.meteor.com | sh
* Rebuilt URL to: https://install.meteor.com/
*   Trying 52.73.238.209...
* Connected to install.meteor.com (52.73.238.209) port 443 (#0)
* SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
* Closing connection 0
```

I'm **not** behind the proxy and other SSL sites are loading fine through `curl`, e.g.

```
$ curl https://www.example.com
<!doctype html>
...
$ curl https://www.google.co.uk
<!doctype html>
...
```

How do I update `meteor` package, or maybe there is some other simple way to achieve that?

---

My environment (OS X):

```
$ meteor --version
Meteor version 0.5.2
$ node --version
v0.10.44
$ curl --version
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
```

Comment: Probably the old version really cannot connect. I noticed that `http://install.meteor.com` redirects to https, so most probably the old version does not know how to handle the redirect. You will need to uninstall the old version, then download and install manually the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `meteor update` or `npm` fails, `meteor` can be installed/updated by using the Meteor install script available at https://install.meteor.com/.

However using `curl` it has some issues to deal with the old certificate.

So using `wget` instead seems to work fine:

```
wget -qO- https://install.meteor.com | sh
```

If the old version of `meteor` was installed via `npm`, it should be uninstalled first:

```
npm remove meteor -g
```